# How to insert on conflict if id is autogenerated in sprinframework jdbc

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jdbc, psql

I'm trying to insert or update data into spring jdbc query with on conflict query. id is generated automatically by spring so that id will be null if not exists in database.

How can i solve an insert into on conflict update with autogenerated id?

`@Query("INSERT INTO XXX (id, name, year) VALUES(NULL, John, 2019) ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET name = :name")`

I expect the output to insert if there's no id (or id is NULL) and update name if id is in database table

Comment: You can't do this. There won't be a conflict, because the ID will always be newly generated. In addition comparisons with null are tricky in SQL. You might want to rethink your approach, and phrase your question with a description of what you are trying to achieve, because this sounds like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: ok thanks for your help